# How to split screen into 2 columns and have divs in the 2nd column match information on the first one?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to have divs with videos on my right column appear next to certain paragraphs in my left column I can't however find a way to do so. I've tried table cells, rows and dummy divs but I can never place the div exactly where I want it without deformating the left column.

```css
      .row {
     align-items: center;
          display: flex;
        }
        .bg-red {
          background: red;
        }
        .col-6 {
          width: 50%;
        }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
          <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab tempora quas tenetur, quae aliquid fugiat nam voluptates quisquam mollitia iusto quod doloremque natus recusandae! Ea cumque officiis numquam expedita tenetur!</p>
          <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab tempora quas tenetur, quae aliquid fugiat nam voluptates quisquam mollitia iusto quod doloremque natus recusandae! Ea cumque officiis numquam expedita tenetur!</p>
          <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab tempora quas tenetur, quae aliquid fugiat nam voluptates quisquam mollitia iusto quod doloremque natus recusandae! Ea cumque officiis numquam expedita tenetur!</p>
          <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab tempora quas tenetur, quae aliquid fugiat nam voluptates quisquam mollitia iusto quod doloremque natus recusandae! Ea cumque officiis numquam expedita tenetur!</p>
           <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab tempora quas tenetur, quae aliquid fugiat nam voluptates quisquam mollitia iusto quod doloremque natus recusandae! Ea cumque officiis numquam expedita tenetur!</p>
          <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab tempora quas tenetur, quae aliquid fugiat nam voluptates quisquam mollitia iusto quod doloremque natus recusandae! Ea cumque officiis numquam expedita tenetur!</p>
          <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab tempora quas tenetur, quae aliquid fugiat nam voluptates quisquam mollitia iusto quod doloremque natus recusandae! Ea cumque officiis numquam expedita tenetur!</p>
          <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab tempora quas tenetur, quae aliquid fugiat nam voluptates quisquam mollitia iusto quod doloremque natus recusandae! Ea cumque officiis numquam expedita tenetur!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
          <video width="100%" height="300" controls>
              <source   src="https://cdn.plyr.io/static/demo/View_From_A_Blue_Moon_Trailer-576p.mp4" type="video/mp4">
          </video>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row bg-red">
        <div class="col-6">
         
          <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab tempora quas tenetur, quae aliquid fugiat nam voluptates quisquam mollitia iusto quod doloremq natus recusandae! Ea cumque officiis numquam expedita tenetur!</p>
          <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab tempora quas tenetur, quae aliquid fugiat nam voluptates quisquam mollitia iusto quod doloremque natus recusandae! Ea cumque officiis numquam expedita tenetur!</p>
          <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab tempora quas tenetur, quae aliquid fugiat nam voluptates quisquam mollitia iusto quod doloremque natus recusandae! Ea cumque officiis numquam expedita tenetur!</p>
          <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab tempora quas tenetur, quae aliquid fugiat nam voluptates quisquam mollitia iusto quod doloremque natus recusandae! Ea cumque officiis numquam expedita tenetur!</p>
          <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab tempora quas tenetur, quae aliquid fugiat nam voluptates quisquam mollitia iusto quod doloremque natus recusandae! Ea cumque officiis numquam expedita tenetur!</p>
          <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab tempora quas tenetur, quae aliquid fugiat nam voluptates quisquam mollitia iusto quod doloremque natus recusandae! Ea cumque officiis numquam expedita tenetur!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
          <video width="100%" height="300" controls>
              <source   src="https://cdn.plyr.io/static/demo/View_From_A_Blue_Moon_Trailer-576p.mp4" type="video/mp4">
          </video>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This code example shows somehow close to what I want but the video div is just centered in the right column. I want to be able to place a video next to the 2nd paragraph for example and then another next to the 4th and so on.

Comment: you should set a single paragraph into your .col-6 elements. If no videos are to be aside, leave it empty ;)

Comment: My first reaction would be to play with `float`s -- somehow set the main content area 100% wide, but all your `p` tags to only take up the left 50% and the video to float right on the other 50% -- you may need to play around with `display` `inline`|`block`|`inline-block` (trial and error)

Comment: oh ... so you have to maintain the format/structure of the left column?

Comment: yeah i dont want it to mess the structure on the left column or mess it up as little as possible

Comment: I tought on having my p tags take only 50% of the screen and filling the right side with dummy divs until the place I wanted my video to be. My problem there is the size of the dummy div would be diferent depending on the resolution/screen of the viewer

Answer (score 0):

I'm making a few assumptions about the end result you're trying to achieve, but if what you're looking for is something like...

> Vertically and horizontally aligning the text and respective videos to their available space

And from you comment...

> *" I want to be able to place a video next to the 2nd paragraph for example and then another next to the 4th and so on"*

Then the best way to achieve that is actually with the [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) framework you're already using.

1. **Don't override the default [Grid System](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/)**

   - You should just remove most of the `CSS` code you've implemented, which is redundantly overriding the layout styling provided by those very same classes `.col-6` and `.row`
2. **Use [flex utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/)**

   - Bootstrap comes with additional layout utilities as classes *(`.d-flex .flex-column .justify-content-center .align-items-center`)*, which implement [flex-box](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) properties. These will allow you to achieve very flexible alignment of relative elements based on their available space.

     - [.d-flex](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/#enable-flex-behaviors)
     - [.flex-column](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/#direction)
     - [.justify-content-center](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/#justify-content)
     - [.align-items-center](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/#align-items)

```css
.bg-red {
   background: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <div class="col-6 p-2">
            <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab tempora quas tenetur, quae aliquid fugiat
                nam voluptates quisquam mollitia iusto quod doloremque natus recusandae! Ea cumque officiis numquam
                expedita tenetur!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 p-2">
            <video width="100%" controls>
                <source src="https://cdn.plyr.io/static/demo/View_From_A_Blue_Moon_Trailer-576p.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bg-red d-flex flex-row justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <div class="col-6 p-2">
            <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab tempora quas tenetur, quae aliquid fugiat
                nam voluptates quisquam mollitia iusto quod doloremque natus recusandae! Ea cumque officiis numquam
                expedita tenetur!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 p-2">
            <video width="100%" controls>
                <source src="https://cdn.plyr.io/static/demo/View_From_A_Blue_Moon_Trailer-576p.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <div class="col-6 p-2">
            <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab tempora quas tenetur, quae aliquid fugiat
                nam voluptates quisquam mollitia iusto quod doloremque natus recusandae! Ea cumque officiis numquam
                expedita tenetur!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 p-2">
            <video width="100%" controls>
                <source src="https://cdn.plyr.io/static/demo/View_From_A_Blue_Moon_Trailer-576p.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bg-red d-flex flex-row justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <div class="col-6 p-2">
            <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab tempora quas tenetur, quae aliquid fugiat
                nam voluptates quisquam mollitia iusto quod doloremque natus recusandae! Ea cumque officiis numquam
                expedita tenetur!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 p-2">
            <video width="100%" controls>
                <source src="https://cdn.plyr.io/static/demo/View_From_A_Blue_Moon_Trailer-576p.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: My example wasn't the best. What you made works for that example but I have like a huge wall of text that i can't split into blocks. And I want to connect some words or sentances throughout the text to the videos showing them on the right side of the place where that word/sentance happens